# Python cannot import function from module in same package

Tags: python

I have this package structure

```
project/
    package_a/
        __init__.py
        subpackage_b/
            __init__.py
            module_one.py
        subpackage_c
            __init__.py
            module_two.py
    package_b/
```

module_one.py

```
def test_func():
     return 0
```

How can I import `test_func` from module_two.py? I have tried using

```
from subpackage_b.module_one import test_func

from package_a.subpackage_b.module_one import test_func

from module_one import test_func
```

but none of them works, giving me `ModuleNotFoundError`. I understand there are many similar questions here but none of them seems to work for me. One which I have not tried is setting the `PYTHONPATH` variable, but I am not sure what to set it to. I am using VSCode and the current `python.pythonPath` is just the python file in my venv folder.

Comment: Have you tried the answers that were suggesting to use relative imports?

Comment: how do you invoke python? it affects how your package is picked up.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Any relative imports give me `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Comment: @Kaos I run it directly from VSCode. I also tried running it from my terminal directly but it does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the set of paths that you can import from using

```py
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

So, make sure that the project path is in `sys.path`. If it is not, then you can add it dynamically in your code with the following line, which should be run before your import statements

```py
sys.path.append('C:/Path_to_project/project')
```

However, if you were running python from the project folder, the path should already be there.

The proper way to import when your `sys.path` is including your project folder, would be

```py
from package_a.subpackage_b.module_one import test_func
```

Comment: My project path was not in `sys.path` and indeed appending it allowed the import to succeed. However, I believe I am running it from the project folder so I am not sure why I have to append this in the first place

Comment: probably your project hasn't been set up correctly then

Answer (score 0):

In python, When the interpreter executes the `import` statement, it searches for module in a list of directories assembled from the following sources:

- The directory from which the input script was run, or the current directory if the interpreter is being run interactively
- The list of directories contained in the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, if it is set. (The format for `PYTHONPATH` is OS-dependent but should mimic the `PATH` environment variable.)
- An installation-dependent list of directories configured at the time Python is installed (For example: in linux, `/usr/local/lib/python`)

In addition, You can put the module file in any directory of your choice and then modify `sys.path` at run-time so that it contains that directory but this would not be a standard. you can do it for internal purpose but not a best practice to share your code with this.

Rather you can use python's `__file__` attribute, to get the path and put it in `sys.path` like below:

```
import sys
from os.path import dirname
sys.path.append(dirname(__file__))
```

Answer (score 0):

The root is of course your `sys.path`, and to answer why it does not work for you, I'll assume you attempt to invoke a python file from within your package, which will not allow python to find your package root properly.

Instead, invoke your code from a file directly in your project root (so the package is in the same directory as your main script file).

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path

> As initialized upon program startup, the first item of this list, path[0], is the directory containing the script that was used to invoke the Python interpreter.

```
$ tree
.
├── main.py
└── package_a
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── subpackage_b
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── module_one.py
    └── subpackage_c
        ├── __init__.py
        └── module_two.py
```

```py
# cat main.py 
import package_a.subpackage_c.module_two

# cat package_a/subpackage_b/module_one.py 
def test_func():
    return 0

# cat package_a/subpackage_c/module_two.py 
from package_a.subpackage_b.module_one import test_func
print("test func:", test_func())
```

```
$ python package_a/subpackage_c/module_two.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "package_a/subpackage_c/module_two.py", line 1, in <module>
    from package_a.subpackage_b.module_one import test_func
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package_a'

$ python main.py
test func: 0
```